# Java not creating JFrame with correct size

Tags: java, swing, screen-resolution

I'm creating a `JFrame` with size 800 x 600 on a MacBook Pro 2018 that should according to the "About my Mac" tab has a resolution of 2560 x 1600, however when I display the window it appears much larger than it should be with the width dimension being over 50% of the screen size (test code below).

##Edit by AT.

The original code was already not behaving to my expectation, but I needed to dispel some possibilities & get more info so edited it to this code.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TestFrameSize {
    
    // made attibute to refer to frame in other methods
    JFrame frame; 

    public TestFrameSize() {
        Dimension size = new Dimension(800,600);
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setPreferredSize(size);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        System.out.println("Frame size: " + frame.getSize());
        printProperty("java.version");
        printProperty("os.name");
        getImage();
    }
    
    private void printProperty(String name) {
        System.out.println(name + ": " + System.getProperty(name));
    }
    
    private BufferedImage getImage() {
        Dimension d = frame.getSize();
        BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(d.width, d.height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        
        Graphics2D g = bi.createGraphics();
        Window w = frame;
        w.paint(g);
        g.dispose();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, new ImageIcon(bi));
        
        return bi;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                TestFrameSize test = new TestFrameSize();
            }
        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}
```

And the result:
[image: screenshot of window size]

For a display of 2560x1600 this window is certainly larger than 800x600 should be! This seemed strange and I tried to look up what Java thinks my screen size is with

`Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();`

and this gave the answer 1440 x 900 which is not what the screen should be. Is it that Java is misinterpreting the size of my display?

I'm at a bit of a loss here, googling around I couldn't see any obvious answers and I'm not sure whether this is a Mac thing, a Java thing, or a "I'm not understanding how the screen works" thing.

Comment: `frame.setSize(800,600);` A frame's size should be set according to the preferred size of the content, to account for the different sizes of the frame borders and title bar. Is the frame being created on the.. NVM. For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). Doing so will answer the question I was about to ask, and a dozen more. BTW - don't add a sig, it is noise.

Comment: Thanks, I included an example but I think it might run "normally" elsewhere.

Comment: First up, I put all my test code (including stuff from SO) into a single package. So please give test code a descriptive name so it does not clash with other code. Something like `TestFrameSize` seems appropriate here. OK .. that aside. I'm getting 186 x 593 px here, (Windows) which I think we can both agree is odd. The question I was going to ask before was if the GUI was launched on the Event Dispatch Thread, which it's always good practice to make sure it is. So, I changed the code to do that and got .. the exact same result. ...

Comment: .. I didn't have great hopes that would solve the problem, but it's good to eliminate it early on. Hmm.. I'm going to put some more test in there, do some output to the command line, to help debug what is going and specifically if it changes according to JRE / OS etc. Mind if I post that altered code back into the question? **Edit:** It's getting weirder fast. The frame is reporting that it's 800 x 600 when I `getSize()` after it is on-screen. **Correction of typo:** *" I'm getting 186 x 593 px here"* I meant  **786** x 593 px.

Comment: **Caveat:** Though I'm an experienced Swing developer, I'd never really dug into frame sizes on-screen. I instead work from the 'inside out' - ensuring the content is the right size, the frame is configured to need, then packed in around the content size. Now that I **am** looking more closely at the actual frame size, I really cannot understand what I am seeing. I'll wait to hear about whether you want my test code back into the question. or someone comes along who has seen this behavior before & might be able to shed light on it. In the meantime, why are you setting a frame size, ..

Comment: Sorry this is my first go into Java so I'm not used to convention yet (mostly python that's more fast and loose). Glad it's seeming not just me, but in my case the window seems to be much larger than what what I'd expect, not slightly smaller. But yes, please feel free to add modified code!

Comment: .. OK .. I'll add what I've got in a few minutes then get back to comments.

Comment: I've made the edit. It includes a couple of tweaks to the technique originally seen, but still displays the problem, as well as providing more (confounding) information. For instance, the code pops an image of the frame itself in an option pane. As far as I can tell, the image is **not** the same size as the frame actually appears on-screen! Does it appear the same size for you? (Note that you need to drag the option pane to the left / below the frame to see the effect.)

Comment: I think this has to do with the frames graphics configuration (specifically the default transform). The way swing handles scaling is by storing a reference to a `GraphicsConfiguration` object in each component. The configuration has an `AffineTransform` which is the default transform for the screen device (i.e. offset relative to the main screen and the scaling factor). This transform is used to calculate the size of a frame (e.g. with 200% scaling a `JPanel` that asks to be 100x200px will be 200x400px on the screen). For normal components that is expected behaviour, but for frames...

Comment: the transform shouldn’t be taken into consideration (at least on Windows this is the case). Maybe there is some strange special behaviour on macOS where a `JFrame` actually applies the transform (this can’t be the case for all type of windows as popups behave as expected).

Comment: The option pane is definitely larger than the original frame and displays a java icon followed by a black rectangle that appears to be the same width as frame (but not the same height). I instead tried `fillRect(0,0,frame.WIDTH,frame.HEIGHT)` and this produced a rectangle that was the size of the original frame inside the option pane.
Output:
Frame size: java.awt.Dimension[width=800,height=600]
java.version: 11.0.1
os.name: Mac OS X

Comment: Thanks @weisj, that sounds like that might be it. looking at `frame.getGraphicsConfiguration().getDefaultTransform()` gives `AffineTransform[[2.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 2.0, 0.0]]` which looks like it is scaling by 200%. Is the normal expected behaviour then that the frame itself shouldn't scale but inside components should?

Comment: Yes, I just noticed right now that you set the size by setting the preferred size. This definitely accounts for the scaling factor. If you use `#setSize` directly it should be the exact size you provide.

Comment: I tried with `frame.setSize()` and this leads to a frame that's 80x22, now I'm really at a loss! I think this is possibly something to do with HiDPI displays but I can't really find any definitive answers on how to handle this...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218444/discussion-between-samuel-barnett-and-weisj).

Comment: Apologies, the frame was small because of the `frame.pack()` call below it, it still comes out enlarged

Comment: @weisj *"you set the size by setting the preferred size."* No, that was me, in the edited code. Sorry for the confusion. I saw no difference in the frame size between setting the size and setting the preferred size.